# need take the first two characters from cloumn 6 and append with PLedger and place end of the row, it should work for all rows in csv file

Tags: powershell

need take the first two characters from cloumn 6 and append with PLedger and place end of the row, it should work for all rows in csv file.

**Source file:**

Row1-----
NEW,,2019/11/30,EPBCS,Bonus Accrual,**USD**,2019/11/06,A,4007,,9999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12637.349999999999,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Row2-----
NEW,,2019/11/30,EPBCS,Bonus Accrual,**JPY**,2019/11/06,A,2002,9999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,320356.8225,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

**Expected output file:**

NEW,,2019/11/30,EPBCS,Bonus Accrual,**USD**,2019/11/06,A,4007,,9999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12637.349999999999,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,**PLedger US**,,

Row2-----
NEW,,2019/11/30,EPBCS,Bonus Accrual,**JPY**,2019/11/06,A,2002,,9999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,320356.8225,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,Bonus_Accrual_Nov2019,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,**PLedger JP**,,

Comment: Your appended data is not at the end of each row if there are commas after it in a CSV file. When you convert your CSV data into an object, each column should have a header. Data in a particular column can then be accessed by `$CurrentRow.ColumnName` syntax. You can do something like the following: `$row.LastColumnName = "PLedger {0}" -f $row.column6.substring(0,2)`. Just repeat that over each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
$headers = 1..89 | Foreach-Object { "col{0}" -f $_}
$inFile = Import-Csv file.csv -Header $headers

foreach ($row in $inFile) {
    $row.col89 = "PLedger {0}" -f $row.col6.substring(0,2)
}

# This creates a true CSV output.
# Skip to the next line if you want no headers and unqualified text
$inFile | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType

# Only use this code if you want no quotes and no headers
($inFile | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '"' |
    Set-Content output.csv
```

Since you did not provide headers for your CSV rows, I created them using the format `col1` through `col89`. The `foreach` loop allows `$row` to be a reference of the current item in the `$inFile` array. So when `$row` is updated, the corresponding item in `$inFile` is also updated. `Export-Csv` creates an output file with the manufactured headers.